# How do I set the architecture on install4j?

Tags: install4j, deb

My java application depends on some native libraries. So I need to create an architecture-specific deb (i.e. I need to set the Architecture field to amd64 or x86).  How can I do this with install4j?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, but we'll add this option in 5.1.6. Please contact support to get a build where this is already implemented, We'd be grateful if you could test this at your end.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it doesn't answer to your question very accurately but you can already create an architecture-specific Debian package with [JDeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb). Look at [this example](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb/blob/master/src/examples/ant/src/deb/control/control), replace "all" by the correct architecture.