# Install4j: Is there a way to dertermine linux architecture?

Tags: install4j

The Util class contains methods to determine whether it's being run on 32 vs 64 bit Windows, but I don't see anything for linux.  Is anything available for differentiating linux architectures?

Thanks...

Comment: I guess this is very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911708/how-do-i-set-the-architecture-on-install4j which asked about architecture as well, although I'm mainly concerned with 32/64 bit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "Run executable" action to call

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

and redirect the output to an installer variable. The output is either 32 or 64.